# How to use Group By in seedstack?

Tags: java, seedstack

I want to use Group By in Seedstack, to count lines and sum certain values.

eg : I have this table "employee" in database :

```
id  name    section value
----------------------------
1   Chun    DDE     5
2   Tom     DMD     8
3   Diana   DMD     18
4   Frisk   DDE     2
5   Laura   DVD     10
6   Chris   DMD     15
```

And I need something like this equivalent in SQL:

```
SELECT section, count(1) as staff, sum(value) as result FROM employee group by section;
    section staff   result
    ------------------------
    DDE     2       7
    DMD     3       41
    DVD     1       10
```

What is the best way to do this in seedstack ?

Answer (score 1):

SeedStack does its relational db access through the JPA or the JDBC standards:

- JPA is a "higher level" API that Object-Relational Mapping (ORM).
- JDBC is a "lower level" API that allows to directly execute SQL.

I recommend you to go the JPA route. You can learn how to configure and use it with SeedStack here: http://seedstack.org/guides/jpa

When using the business framework, persistence operations are encapsulated in [repositories](http://seedstack.org/docs/business/repositories/) that you need to extend to go beyond built-in abilities. In a method of your [custom repository](http://seedstack.org/addons/jpa/business/#custom-jpa-repository) you can use the full JPA API by obtaining the JPA EntityManager interface with `getEntityManager()`.

As for the JPA equivalent to Group By, you have can use either the criteria API or the JPQL query language. You can read this for more information: https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/group.

If you have JPA working fine, you can repost a more specific question with the JPA tag (regardless of using SeedStack or not).